# how to click buttons that have the same name in python-selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I just started using selenium and came accross this website: https://equi.generali.fr/devis-en-ligne-proprietaire-d-un-equide

there are these buttons:

[image]

with the following elements:

for yes:

[image]

and for no:

[image]

From what I can see both buttons have the name "col-auto pax-5 "

I tried using the click function with selenium as shown below using the different id I could find:

```
input_rcpe_yes = driver.find_element_by_id('quote_equine_owner_hasSubscribedRcpe_0')
input_rcpe_no = driver.find_element_by_id('quote_equine_owner_hasSubscribedRcpe_1')

        input_rcpe_yes.click()
```

I have also tried directly changing the values inside from 0 to 1 or vice versa:

```
input_rcpe_yes.send_keys('value', 1)
time.sleep(2)
input_rcpe_no.send_keys('value', 0)
```

is there something i am missing? how do I manage to use .click for these particular cases?

If you need more info, I am trying to take every possible variable and store the prices. I managed to loop the list of elements to be able to get the year and price of gear, but having issues with these buttons.

Below is my code:

```
btn_cookie = driver.find_element_by_id('popin_tc_privacy_button')
btn_cookie.click()

input_year = driver.find_element_by_id('quote_equine_owner_equineBirthYear')

input_gear = driver.find_element_by_id('quote_equine_owner_equineValue')

input_rcpe_yes = driver.find_element_by_id('quote_equine_owner_hasSubscribedRcpe_0')
input_rcpe_no = driver.find_element_by_id('quote_equine_owner_hasSubscribedRcpe_1')

input_sub_yes = driver.find_element_by_id('quote_equine_owner_subscribeVeterinaryCharge_0')
input_sub_no = driver.find_element_by_id('quote_equine_owner_subscribeVeterinaryCharge_1')

options_year = []
for option in input_year.find_elements_by_tag_name('option'):
    options_year.append(option.get_attribute("value"))

options_gear = []
for option in input_gear.find_elements_by_tag_name('option'):
    options_gear.append(option.get_attribute("value"))

yes_no = ['yes','no']

for i in yes_no:
    if i == 'yes':
        input_rcpe_yes.send_keys('value', 1)
        time.sleep(2)
        input_rcpe_no.send_keys('value', 0)
    else:
        input_rcpe_no.send_keys('value', 1)
        time.sleep(2)
        input_rcpe_yes.send_keys('value', 0)
    for x in yes_no:
        if x == 'yes':
            input_sub_yes.click()
            time.sleep(2)
        else:
            input_sub_no.click()
            time.sleep(2)
        for year in options_year:
            input_year.send_keys(year)
            time.sleep(2)
            if int(year) > 2000:
                for price in options_gear:
                    input_gear.send_keys(price)
                    time.sleep(2)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few different ways to find elements in selenium. Have a look at these options.
https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html

One of those should work for you :)

Answer (score 0):

Things to be noted for this issue.

1. You need to scroll to the particular web element in order to let Selenium know where this element in UI.
2. Launch browser in full screen.
3. Use Explicit waits.
4. Try manual click on the particular web element, and see if it works manually.

**Code**

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_path)
driver.maximize_window()
#driver.implicitly_wait(50)
driver.get("https://equi.generali.fr/devis-en-ligne-proprietaire-d-un-equide");
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "popin_tc_privacy_button"))).click()
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[data-toggle='buttons']")))).pause(5).perform()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@class,'form-check')]"))).click()
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
```